# Reliably waiting for page to load or reflow in Awesomium.NET 1.7+

Tags: awesomium

Which is the recommended way of waiting for a page to load/reflow in Awesomium.NET 1.7+ when running in a non-UI environment? I've tried this approach:

```
using (var view = WebCore.CreateWebView(...))
{
    // Load page, resize view etc.
    // ...

    do
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        WebCore.Update();
    } while (view.IsLoading);

    // Do something with the page
    // ...
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work reliably - if I render the page to a bitmap after the loop it pretty often comes out blank (but not always). Is there a better way of waiting for page load/reflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you do it depends on what you are waiting for. The code in the question should work when waiting for a page to load, but resizing the view is different - check out the `BitmapSurface.Resized` event, it fires when the `BitmapSurface` has been resized and updated its buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Try subscribing to the WebView.DocumentReady event.

Comment: DocumentReady only means HTML has been loaded but the JavaScript hasn't occurred yet so usually isn't useful if the JavaScript it going to change the HTML that initially loaded or take you to another page.

http://docs.awesomium.net/html/E_Awesomium_Core_WebView_DocumentReady.htm